# Mongorestore don't know what to do with file "db/collection.bson", skipping

Tags: mongodb

I want to migrate my mongodb from 2.0 to 3.0. So I followed the official doc to use mongodump to backup my dbs and use mongorestore to restore the dbs to mongodb 3.0.

But when I use mongorestore, it tells me "don't know what to do with file "db/collection.bson", skipping...".

Nothing to do. How could I migrate my dbs?

Thanks.

EDIT: Here is my steps.

Use mongodump in mongodb 2.0

```
mongodump
tree dump
    db
    ├── collection-1.bson
    ├── collection-2.bson
    ├── collection-3.bson
    ├── ...
```

Copy db directory to mongodb 3.0 server.

On the mongodb 3.0 server calls `mongorestore db`

But I get this error:

```
mongorestore db
2015-03-10T09:36:26.237+0800    building a list of dbs and collections   to restore from db dir
2015-03-10T09:36:26.237+0800    don't know what to do with file "db/collection-1.bson", skipping...
2015-03-10T09:36:26.237+0800    don't know what to do with file "db/collection-2.bson", skipping...
2015-03-10T09:36:26.237+0800    don't know what to do with file "db/collection-3.bson", skipping...
...
2015-03-10T09:36:26.237+0800    done
```

Comment: How are you running mongorestore? Post your command line and the full error message.

Comment: You want to `mongorestore` the `dump` folder, not the `db` folder.

Comment: The folder is right. I just copy the db folder to mongodb 3.0 server.  Otherwise ``mongorestore`` couldn't find the ``bson`` files.

Comment: @wdberkeley got to the root of it for me - I had copied by bson/json files from too deep in the dump tree. I just made a dir with the db name and moved them all back down a level and restore worked fine.

Comment: skipp indexes while restore db ,
`mongorestore -d <dbname>  --noIndexRestore dump_dir/dbname ` and probably you should have index schema script of you own database

Answer (score 146, accepted):

It seems one must also specify -d  in 3.0 like this:

```
mongorestore -d db db
```

Comment: Amazing, it works. How did you know that ? I've never specify ``-d``  param before, mongorestore can auto create the db and restore from the directory. I never thought that I must specify ``-d``.

Comment: In some cases (with new major versions of some tools), there might be a breakage in some of the code paths of the upgraded tool or simply a changed CLI interface. In the above case in order to figure out why the behaviour of the tool has changed I tried first to restore a specific collection from a _db_ directory together with `-d` and `-c` flags (to specify database and specific collection). After that worked, I removed the specific collection and the `-c` flag and it still worked and had imported all the collections.

Comment: deprecated in 3.4  `the --db and --collection args should only be used when restoring from a BSON file. Other uses are deprecated and will not exist in the future; use --nsInclude instead`

Comment: not working for me --db and --collection args should only be used when restoring from a BSON file. Other uses are deprecated and will not exist in the future; use --nsInclude instead, even tried mongorestore --host localhost --port 4023 --nsInclude 'mars.*' --dir=mars/

Comment: Thank you! This was my problem as well. I was not using the DB option because I was restoring using a URI connection string and the mongorestore docs said that other options don't work when using the URI. Bravo!

Comment: Mongo 4.4 now has separate [\`database-tools\`](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/installation/#versioning). I find the thread about `-d` being deprecated confusing. I don't see evidence in the [\`database-tools\` docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#std-option-mongodump.--db). My use case was simple: mongodump (creates folder with stuff), then mongorestore (point to the folder)--but I also needed `-d` to avoid the OP's error.

Answer (score 40):

This answer isn't directly  related to your issue case, but the same error output you will receive trying to restore mongo data, dumped with [`--archive`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--archive) option, available since MongoDB 3.2 version. To resolve this you need to specify [`--gzip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption--gzip) parameter in your `mongorestore` command. Example:

```
mongorestore -d destination_db --gzip /path/to/source/db
```

Comment: Actually, looks like the `mongodump` option is also called [--gzip](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-gzip)

Comment: `--archive` may trigger [this mongorestore bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-2580), and `--uri` may trigger [this other one](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-2583)

Answer (score 6):

If you have lost your mongoDb just try running this command:

```
mongorestore -d destination-db --gzip source-db
```

Where:

- `destination-db` is the name of the destination database
- `source-db` is the name of the source database.

Comment: What if the source and destination DBs are on different servers?

Answer (score 4):

In order to import data to your mongodb ,You need to specify **--db configuration** in mongorestore function with name and path, this works for me for bson and json files as well:

```
mongorestore --db <dbName> <dbPath>
```

check the data was imported properly using mongo cli

```
mongo
show databases
use <dbName>
show collections
```

Answer (score 4):

Following command worked for me in **mongoDB 6.0** -

```
mongorestore --host localhost --port 27017 --db DB-NAME DB-BACKUP-PATH
```

Please replace **DB-NAME** and **DB-BACKUP-PATH** with your actual values. For ex.

```
mongorestore --host localhost --port 27017 --db demo_db /home/ubuntu/db-backup
```

Where "/home/ubuntu/db-backup" contains all collections in bson and json format.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
mongorestore -db dataBaseName dataBasePath
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related to your situation but someone could stumble upon this post with similar error for this reason

In my case, the data was provided to me and had been dumped using

```
mongodump --db ${DB_NAME} --gzip -o ${BACKUP_FILE_GZ}
```

To restore, you must use following format:

```
mongorestore --gzip --db "${DB_NAME_RESTORE}" ${BACKUP_FILE_GZ}/${DB_NAME}
```

Answer (score 0):

With mongorestore, the path of those dump files is a required parameter; you've got that right so far, by indicating db.

It is also a good idea as Peter has said to indicate a database to restore the dump files into collections with a /d switch.

Something I didn't realize while struggling with this is that a mongod must be running to consume the restoration. If you have more than 1 mongod running, you should definitely indicate a port with the --port switch.  The code that worked for me was:

```
mongod --dbpath config --port 27019 --logpath log.config --logappend
```

And in another CLI:

```
mongorestore --port 27019 /d config config
```

followed by

```
mongo localhost:27019/config
```

to verify that the collections were filled properly.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run `mongorestore` on the `dump` directory, not the `db/` directory.

```
mongorestore  dump/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mongorestore --uri "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@<host>" -d <dbname>  <dump dir. address ./something/like/this>
```

This work fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I used docker to start my mongo db instance & I had default username and password
auth set for database.
Below is how my restore looked like.

```
mongorestore --authenticationDatabase admin -u root -p example -d test-db /data/test-db
```

So in-short something of this sort should work.

```
mongorestore --authenticationDatabase admin -u {USERNAME} -p {PASSWORD} -d {DB_NAME} {/DUMP_PATH}
```